# KSQL UDF access ROWPARTITION and similar information

Tags: ksqldb

I have a custom UDF that I can pass a struct to:

`select my_udf(a.my_data) from MY_STREAM a;`

What I would like to do, is pass all info from my stream to that custom UDF:

`select my_udf(a) from MY_STREAM a;`

That way I can access the row partition, time, offset, etc. Unfortunately, KSQL does not understand my intent:

`SELECT column 'A' cannot be resolved`

Any idea how I could work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to pass in a full row into a UDF, only columns, and `a` is the name of the stream, not a column name.

You can change your UDF, to accept multiple parameters, eg, `my_udf(my_data, ROWTIME, ROWPARTITION)` to pass in an the needed metadata individually.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of